# Dynamic number of days to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, dynamic

I'm trying to get to work a query where I need all the properties, whose payments expired in X number of days. X is defined by the property's community, what I have right now is the following:

```
Property.joins(:community).joins(:payments).where("payments.expiration_date = current_date + interval communities.sms_defaulting_days + ' days'")
```

Which is not working, as it does not recognize communities (I believe it's a parsing issue), the error I get is:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "communities"
```

which makes sense to me.

What I'm trying to achieve is that the last part of the query should look like this:

```
payments.expiration_date = current_date + interval '2 days'
```

And I'd get the 2 from "community.sms_defaulting_days"

Another way to think about it is "expiration_date = 2.days.from_now", but I still have the same problem, as I do not know how to make it work dynamically.

Comment: Replace `interval communities.sms_defaulting_days + ' days'` as `'#{communities.sms_defaulting_days} days'::INTERVAL` .. and let me know.

Comment: Is `.where("payments.expiration_date = DATE_ADD(#{current_date}, INTERVAL #{interval})")` any closer to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @sebkomianos what would interval be in this case? I need to extract the date depending on the property's community

Comment: @Waclock In order to fix the syntax error your initial query should be `"payments.expiration_date = current_date + communities.sms_defaulting_days + ' days'"` (take the `interval` part off)

Comment: @sebkomianos I get the following error if I remove interval:
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousFunction: ERROR:  operator is not unique: date + unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write the code as :

```
Property.joins(:community)
        .joins(:payments)
        .where("payments.expiration_date = current_date + (communities.sms_defaulting_days || ' days')::interval")
```

Comment: I get "undefined local variable or method 'communities'" which is probably because communities is not a ruby variable.

Comment: @Waclock I am sure you have a db table `communities` right ?

Comment: Yes, each property has a community_id (belongs_to :community)

Comment: @Waclock Please try now

Comment: I tried again and got the error: 

`PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: " days"`